# It is possible to pass two parameters to a modal

Tags: java, html, jsp, bootstrap-4

I wanted to know if it's possible to use this method to pass 2 parameter to a modal page

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"
 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal_<%=oa.getIdOne()%>_<%=oa.getIdtwo()%>">
</button>

<jsp:include page="newModal.jsp">
   <jsp:param value="<%= oa.getIdOne()%>" name="idone"/>
   <jsp:param value="<%= oa.getIdTwo()%>" name="idtwo"/>
  </jsp:include>
```

When I reload the page the button doesn't work and and when I remove the - an internal error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I solved.
In the modal file i set the dive:

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="editModal_<%= idone %>_<%= idtwo%>" role="dialog"> 
</div>
```